# Is a unique ID the best partition key for CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to determine the best partition key for a CosmosDB table that has both a customer ID (unique value for each customer) and  customer city (in North America, which yields thousands of possible values).

Reading the Azure documentation, I see a lot of conflicting information between which one is best. Some of the documents specify that the more unique value will provide a better spread of items across partitions. While other documents state that using city would be best.

So my question(s) are:

1. Is each partition key hashed and does each partition contain items with keys with a range of hashes? Ie - if Customer ID is the partition key, would one partition have ID's 1 through 1000, another partition 1000 through 2000, etc? Same with city, would one partition have multiple cities? Or, would each partition be mapped 1:1 to a specific partition key - ie ID or city?
2. Based on the above, which one would be better (more performant, cost less)? Having as granular partition key as possible (id customer ID)? Or customer city?

Thank you!

Comment: no one can tell you what would work best for your particular application. having a partition per record doesnt give you any benefit and can potentially cause issues if you will have to do cross partition queries

Answer (score 5):

- yes, partition keys are hashed and those hashes determine where logical partitions are physically stored
- no, partitions will only ever contain records with the same partition key (that's basically the point, co-locate associated records). So in your example, they would be mapped 1:1
- cost is irrelevant because you aren't charged for partitions (although they do have a size limit), so the question comes down to performance, and again that all depends on how your application queries the data.

A good analogy for understanding how partitioning works is to think about finding someone's address:

If I gave you the key to my house (Item ID) but nothing else, you would need to try every door in the world until you happen to stumble upon the right one (aka cross-partition query). If I told you the country (partition key), then you can immediately eliminate a millions of doors, but you'd still have millions of doors to check, so still not very efficient. If I gave you the city, less again but still a lot to check....but if I gave you my postcode, then we've just optimized a query from billions of records to 15-20.

Comment: probably a bad example, how do you know if zip codes dont clash in different countries?

Comment: @4c74356b41 why does that make it a bad example? The point still stands, you'd have a very small dataset to search, even if the very very small chance of them clashing globally happened. The PK isn't supposed to be unique...

Comment: hashing country + zip code would be a strictly better option. again, I'm not sure how uniformly people are distributed across zip codes (my guess: not at all) so using zip code would probably be an inherently bad PK leading to hot partitions

Comment: @4c74356b41 sorry but I disagree, you've completely over analyzed a simple analogy, and based it on total guess work - enlighten me, what's the ratio of duplicate postcodes across countries? Also, given its not a literal example and I've used a quick stat in the UK which is approx 15-20 addresses under a postcode, can you elaborate on why you think that lead would lead to hot partitions?

Comment: why does it matter whats the ratio, if even a single dupe exists zip + country would be a strictly better PK. a zip code is just a proxy for location. grouping people by location will always lead to hot partition(s), because (guess what), most people tend to live in big cities, so people are already grouped by location and you are just replicating that in your db design. thats not smart.

Comment: @4c74356b41 it matters because we are talking about performance, if a PK happens to include a couple of records from a different country - so what? For a start, the performance would be negligible, and again as I've said *it's about how you query the data*. Your comment about hot partitioning still doesn't make sense, if you use Postcode you are narrowing a search from potentially millions of records down to 10-20, in what way is that going to lead to hot partitioning? I've given the example of why Country or City (at least on their own) aren't great PKs, you seem to have missed the point

Comment: why do you think its 10-20? why do you think those are uniformly distributed?